# package com.google.api.client.http.apache doesn't exist when importing project from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, package, android-gradle-plugin, google-api-java-client

I am in the process of migrating project from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio. Progress went smooth until I run the project.

I got several **package doesn't exist** errors:

```
Error:(34, 41) error: package com.google.api.client.http.apache does not exist
Error:(81, 19) error: cannot find symbol variable transport
Error:(81, 36) error: cannot find symbol class ApacheHttpTransport
Error:(170, 27) error: cannot find symbol variable transport
Error:(170, 44) error: cannot find symbol class ApacheHttpTransport
```

The packages was related to Google's API Client library. I added the dependencies manually by scanning through [Maven Repository page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.client):

```
compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-auth-oauth:1.2.3-alpha'
compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-http:1.2.3-alpha'
compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-apache:1.2.3-alpha'
```

However, I can't seems to find the right dependency for `com.google.api.client.http.apache`. Someone care to share the right way to add this dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current Android Studio and/or Gradle use

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.28.0'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.28.0'
```

Source: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client